# How to get started with Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, web-deployment-project

I am completely new at web development. I recently got an internship through my competitive coding skills and didn't know what they offered. So, apparently, they work with SpringBoot and I have no skills regarding this. I searched online but got confused with so many materials. I need to know from the basic to the end with the necessary skills required for this.

Can someone please tell me the exact topics I should cover in sequence. I just want the topics in a sequence that I should learn and if you know particular links for those topics then that too.

Thank you in advance for helping!

Comment: Commit to one full tutorial, then if you need help, seek out other tutorials. This one is a good primer: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring_boot/index.htm

Comment: Can you tell like prerequisites of this and how do I do that. Something that I can stick to for continuing in a sequence

Comment: I found learning Spring boot a bit hard, I watched a lot of tutorials and they all use different methods and ways to implement the same thing. The best way to learn is to do a test project I would say. Where you can use Spring Boot, Spring Data Jpa, Security and so on. First of all google about these three that I wrote and understand what they are. Search for Hibernate too. Two tutorials that helped me a lot were:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DKlTBBuc32c
And this channel :
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCgj2iw9vh5eX50YvKFZnpbw
Good luck!